# Can pyglet run in new thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, pyglet

I would like to run pyglet in a separate thread so that I can implement a user interface for input without being blocked by `pyglet.app.run()`.

```
import pyglet
class Window(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        pyglet.window.Window.__init__(self, visible=True)
        self.push_handlers(on_draw=self.on_draw)
        self.im = pyglet.resource.image('image.jpg')
        pyglet.app.run()

    def on_draw(self):
        self.clear()

import threading
class Thread(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        w = Window()
```

Running

```
Window()
```

works fine. However, running

```
t = Thread()
t.start()
```

results in `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`, which is caused by the call to `pyglet.resource.image()`. Omitting that call eliminates the problem.

Specifically, what is causing this problem, and how can I correct it? More generally, what is the recommended way to render a window using pyglet while allowing for other program execution? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Pyglet uses OpenGL, and OpenGL stuff interacts in strange ways with threads. Perhaps you could leave the main thread to pyglet and put your UI code into another thread? Or try integrating with pyglet's event loop and avoid the whole threading mess.

Comment: @delnan I don't know that the problem involves OpenGL since the offending line only reads a file. Spawning a new thread for the UI code is a good thought and may be an option. I considered integrating with pyglet's event loop via its scheduler, but I don't think that would suffice for a GUI's event loop. Perhaps the best option is to replace the default event loop altogether, but I was hoping for a "preferred" method since this is ["strongly discouraged"](http://pyglet.org/doc/programming_guide/dispatching_events_manually.html).

Comment: pyglet.resource.image() works different as usual. You need first to inform what is the base path that a set of images are located. For this, you can use pyglet.resource.path = ["/base/path/here"]